# How Do I Get Into App Development For Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Recently I'v been introduced to **App Development For Android**. I know the java programming language fairly well therefore I wanted to keep going forward to expand my knowledge into greater and more enjoyable parts of programming.

**1)** What is the best way to start with android development after having a background with java?

**2)** What is the best source to learn from? (sites, videos, books - I'll accept everything).

**3)** What path of learning do I need to follow? (What to learn first, how to go from there).

My final goal is to get the hang of *android studio* and start making my own apps.

**Thank you for reading! any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to start with the free android coarse on Udacity.which has been given by the Google itself.they teach through basic so that even the one with no experience could make sense.i have refered several sources but this has been most helpful.

In this set of vedios you will get to know almost everything about Android development.i can say upto intermediate professional level.

Once you got that strong foundation you have to go through the Documenting of android SDK.it will give you an amazing exposure.if you are not so much patient searching guy then there is always stackoverflow for you.

Even Google suggest  stackoverflow for Android development.
Make sure you learn by building things.
Don't expect to under stand everything at first you will get clarity on time.the gradle build system and all will be a bit confusing at first .ignore them until it's working.

Try to copy the apps that's already installed on you phone.

Use network and all such API you can possibly implement.

Anyway all the best and welcome to android development.

Comment: thank you! much appreciated.